# twitter type head rails not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails gem but the text_field does nothing. I removed //= require turbolinks from application.js to see if that had anything to do with it.

new.html.erb

```
 <script>


var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
var matches, substringRegex;

// an array that will be populated with substring matches
matches = [];

// regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

// iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
// contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
$.each(strs, function(i, str) {
  if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
    matches.push({ value: str });
  }
});

cb(matches);
 };
};


var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
   'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
   'Idaho', 'Illinois ];

$('#thebasics').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});


</script>


<%= f.text_field :school, :id => "thebasics", :class => "fr-input", :placeholder => "states" %>
```

what am I missing?

I think it is the script not running because I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your missing apostrophe after Illinois.
Second, your typeahead needs something to initialize it. Try calling it in `$(document).ready` and it will work fine as long as you have the Typeahead files included in your asset pipeline. I'd move your JS to a separate instead of having it in your view. This is how I tested it and it worked.

yourSearch.js:

```
 var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;

        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                matches.push({
                    value: str
                });
            }
        });

        cb(matches);
    };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
   'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
   'Idaho', 'Illinois' ];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#thebasics').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'states',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: substringMatcher(states)
  });
});
```

Make sure that is loaded into your asset pipeline along with the Typeahead source files.

Comment: Do you have `typeahead.bundle.min.js` or equivalent in your app/assets/javascripts directory and is your application.js file aware of it, either by autoloading all files or explicitly including it? After that, move your JS code from your view into its own JS file, also in the asset pipeline, remove the `<script>` and `</script>` tags, and initialize the typeahead within `$(document).ready(function(){});`. 

I did exactly this and your code worked.

Comment: how do I initialize it? remove <script> in the file in the assets folder?

Comment: You can't have <script> tags in a .js file, so remove those. You initialize the typeahead by telling Javascript, "on this event, perform this action." The code sample in my answer above did the trick for me. I am going to modify my answer so you can see the entire .js file.

Comment: quick question, in the states var, how can I change that to equal to all my users? example var users = @users.all?

Comment: and I want it to only start suggesting if the user enters "~" as the first character but I'm reading now on how to get that going

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos Getting data to your script from Rails is really another discussion. If you want to make a new question and link me, we can talk about it.